# meteor server side bulk database changes

Tags: meteor

Is there any way in meteor to do bulk changes in published collections in server side?... like updating/inserting hundreds or thousands records without each individual record being sent to all subscribers one by one?

I am pulling in periodically third party data and just want to gather all updates or inserts in one pull as one batch update so all clients will receive it as one change package not thousands of mini-updates. Doing it one by one creates a big bottleneck in my app atm.

If there is no support in meteor for this atm then should i just do the updates directly to mongo and let meteor to pick it up on the next mongo poll?

```js
// imagine myChanges array with 1000 items
myChanges.forEach(function(change){
    // this will trigger the sync with clients immediately... 1000 times
    // currently this will practically hang my server
    // i want to gather the changes here instead
    MyCollection.update({_id: change.docId}, change);
});

// and trigger the sync here instead
```

Thanks,
Reio

Comment: Are there any code/samples you have to describe the issue?. Meteor already only sends down the differences to the client. There is an initial sync with all the data you want to publish, followed by any changes (diffs only) to the client when you edit the data.

Comment: [Relevant](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meteor-talk/batch$20insert/meteor-talk/9qtZQiKlmiQ/wMXl3PuEvAkJ)

Comment: diff does not help me as those are real changes, the documents are changing so they have to be sent to clients. The problem is that they are sent one by one. For example if i change 100 documents in server side using some kind of foreach or loop then each loop cycle will immediately trigger sending the change to the clients. What i want is to hold the sending until the loop is done and trigger the "flush" to send the batch-update that contains all changes done during this loop.

Comment: i see that in client side there is similar undocumented functionality in minimongo: `beginUpdate()`, `endUpdate()`, `.pauseObservers()` and `.resumeObservers()` but cant find anything for server side

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your application is, or how many publish calls you have, this could be acheived by rolling your own Publish functions.

i.e. Instead of

```
Meteor.publish("myCollection", function() {
    return myCollection.find(); } );
```

Create your own Publish / Cursor and add hooks to it.

```
Meteor.publish("myCollection", function() {
    globalObserver = myCollection.find().observe({
        added: function(item) {
            publication.added(item);
        }
        // And So on
     });
```

Your batch updates would then need to interact with this publish function in some way, causing it to stop and re-intialise the observer once your updates are complete.